# .NET C# Tracking Categories on invoice lines Issue (OptionId is empty)

Tags: c#, .net, xero-api

When making an API call using the .NET library for invoices, the tracking categories on the invoice lines have OptionId as en empty GUID. See below.

I'm setting the `UpdatedDateUTC` and it returns one result.

**.NET Code**

```
var query = api.Invoices.Page(page);

page++;

if (lastUpdatedTime.HasValue)
{
    query = query.ModifiedSince(lastUpdatedTime.Value.AsUtc());
}

invoices = query.OrderBy("UpdatedDateUTC").Find();
```

**Tracking category Object in Visual Studio**

```
{Xero.Api.Core.Model.ItemTrackingCategory}
Errors: null
Id: {11692cb7-597c-4064-a4ac-655c60cedd0f}
Name: "Sales Rep"
Option: "Rob"
OptionId: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
ValidationStatus: Ok
Warnings: null
```

When I use the API previewer at api.xero.com I get the following JSON which shows the correct ids. Is there an issue with the .NET library? I was version 2.2.1.6 and tried upgrading to the latest nuget package version 2.2.1.12 with the same issue.

This has been working previously but recently stopped working correctly.

**Response from Xero API Previewer (api.xero.com)**

```
 {
  "Id": "773e95c2-cec5-4f02-90c9-8c224b246e4f",
  "Status": "OK",
  "ProviderName": "Xero API Previewer",
  "DateTimeUTC": "\/Date(1521545151271)\/",
  "Invoices": [
    {
      "Type": "ACCREC",
      "InvoiceID": "87fc8996-d881-47af-9c26-479705bbfb8a",
      "InvoiceNumber": "INV-0088",
      "Reference": "",
      "Prepayments": [],
      "Overpayments": [],
      "CISDeduction": 0.00,
      "AmountDue": 12000.00,
      "AmountPaid": 0.00,
      "SentToContact": false,
      "CurrencyRate": 1.000000,
      "HasErrors": false,
      "IsDiscounted": false,
      "HasAttachments": false,
      "Attachments": [],
      "Contact": {
        "ContactID": "1bbc04e6-0c4a-4dca-9249-b9369759515b",
        "ContactStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "Name": "ELP Aviation",
        "EmailAddress": "",
        "BankAccountDetails": "",
        "Addresses": [
          {
            "AddressType": "STREET",
            "City": "",
            "Region": "",
            "PostalCode": "",
            "Country": ""
          },
          {
            "AddressType": "POBOX",
            "City": "",
            "Region": "",
            "PostalCode": "",
            "Country": ""
          }
        ],
        "Phones": [
          {
            "PhoneType": "DEFAULT",
            "PhoneNumber": "",
            "PhoneAreaCode": "",
            "PhoneCountryCode": ""
          },
          {
            "PhoneType": "DDI",
            "PhoneNumber": "",
            "PhoneAreaCode": "",
            "PhoneCountryCode": ""
          },
          {
            "PhoneType": "FAX",
            "PhoneNumber": "",
            "PhoneAreaCode": "",
            "PhoneCountryCode": ""
          },
          {
            "PhoneType": "MOBILE",
            "PhoneNumber": "",
            "PhoneAreaCode": "",
            "PhoneCountryCode": ""
          }
        ],
        "UpdatedDateUTC": "\/Date(1520356343967+0000)\/",
        "ContactGroups": [],
        "IsSupplier": false,
        "IsCustomer": true,
        "DefaultCurrency": "USD",
        "SalesTrackingCategories": [],
        "PurchasesTrackingCategories": [],
        "ContactPersons": [],
        "HasValidationErrors": false
      },
      "DateString": "2018-03-16T00:00:00",
      "Date": "\/Date(1521158400000+0000)\/",
      "DueDateString": "2018-03-17T00:00:00",
      "DueDate": "\/Date(1521244800000+0000)\/",
      "Status": "AUTHORISED",
      "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
      "LineItems": [
        {
          "ItemCode": "1YR",
          "Description": "SaaS 1 Year",
          "UnitAmount": 12000.00,
          "TaxType": "NONE",
          "TaxAmount": 0.00,
          "LineAmount": 12000.00,
          "AccountCode": "DEFREV",
          "Tracking": [
            {
              "Name": "Revenue",
              "Option": "New Business",
              "TrackingCategoryID": "b054bce6-95e4-49b3-8d3f-6ed35554189c",
              "TrackingOptionID": "509df853-d8d7-4450-b2d8-1d00fe9619a0"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Sales Rep",
              "Option": "Rob",
              "TrackingCategoryID": "11692cb7-597c-4064-a4ac-655c60cedd0f",
              "TrackingOptionID": "7a65b8c4-bba8-457c-9ddf-38d6442b2d49"
            }
          ],
          "Quantity": 1.0000,
          "LineItemID": "c2b527cb-6677-4853-bb52-7263cba71ef9",
          "ValidationErrors": []
        }
      ],
      "SubTotal": 12000.00,
      "TotalTax": 0.00,
      "Total": 12000.00,
      "UpdatedDateUTC": "\/Date(1521230140920+0000)\/",
      "CurrencyCode": "USD"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Raw response from Fiddler:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 19 Mar 2018 00:14:33 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth Realm="api.xero.com"
Xero-Cell: egeby
Content-Length: 2187
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "Id": "f9e4425a-a6fb-4682-b1b0-5ef1c9245727",
  "Status": "OK",
  "ProviderName": "AppNamePrivate (Demo)",
  "DateTimeUTC": "\/Date(1521418474071)\/",
  "Invoices": [
    {
      "Type": "ACCREC",
      "InvoiceID": "87fc8996-d881-47af-9c26-479705bbfb8a",
      "InvoiceNumber": "INV-0088",
      "Reference": "",
      "Payments": [],
      "CreditNotes": [],
      "Prepayments": [],
      "Overpayments": [],
      "AmountDue": 12000.00,
      "AmountPaid": 0.00,
      "AmountCredited": 0.00,
      "CurrencyRate": 1.000000,
      "HasErrors": false,
      "IsDiscounted": false,
      "HasAttachments": false,
      "Contact": {
        "ContactID": "1bbc04e6-0c4a-4dca-9249-b9369759515b",
        "Name": "ELP Aviation",
        "Addresses": [],
        "Phones": [],
        "ContactGroups": [],
        "ContactPersons": [],
        "HasValidationErrors": false
      },
      "DateString": "2018-03-16T00:00:00",
      "Date": "\/Date(1521158400000+0000)\/",
      "DueDateString": "2018-03-17T00:00:00",
      "DueDate": "\/Date(1521244800000+0000)\/",
      "Status": "AUTHORISED",
      "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
      "LineItems": [
        {
          "ItemCode": "1YR",
          "Description": "SaaS 1 Year",
          "UnitAmount": 12000.0000,
          "TaxType": "NONE",
          "TaxAmount": 0.00,
          "LineAmount": 12000.00,
          "AccountCode": "DEFREV",
          "Tracking": [
            {
              "Name": "Revenue",
              "Option": "New Business",
              "TrackingCategoryID": "b054bce6-95e4-49b3-8d3f-6ed35554189c",
              "Options": []
            },
            {
              "Name": "Sales Rep",
              "Option": "Rob",
              "TrackingCategoryID": "11692cb7-597c-4064-a4ac-655c60cedd0f",
              "Options": []
            }
          ],
          "Quantity": 1.0000,
          "LineItemID": "c2b527cb-6677-4853-bb52-7263cba71ef9"
        }
      ],
      "SubTotal": 12000.00,
      "TotalTax": 0.00,
      "Total": 12000.00,
      "UpdatedDateUTC": "\/Date(1521230140920+0000)\/",
      "CurrencyCode": "USD"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Missing information**

As you can see the Fiddler response is missing the TackingOptionId that the API Previewer has. `Invoice.LineItems[].Tracking[].TrackingOptionId`

Comment: What should the value be (rather than an empty guid)?

Comment: Please show the relevant code (client side or server side - impossible to tell what you are asking).

Comment: Can you use something like fiddler to capture the raw response content so we can see if it's being returned by the API at all?

Comment: Added fiddler response and additional information. Seems the fiddler response is missing the TrackingOptionId. @MJMortimer

Comment: I'm not sure the API has ever returned the TracjingOptionID when the tracking is embedded in an invoice line item. It's not in our public documentation either. Are you sure you're not getting mixed up with using tracking via the tracking endpoints?

Comment: Our code in our application has not changed and has worked before using that field. Is "Option" unique in that we could use that to match instead of OptionId?

Comment: @MJMortimer Just need to know if "Option" (Name) is unique? It's not specified in the API docs but the Xero UI seems to only allow unique names.